# Is there a way to transfer data from MC reports to the custom preference center?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to find a way to transfer data from Marketing Cloud reports to custom preference center, so that I can ultimately move it to Sales Cloud.
Does anyone has a suggestion?

The ultimate goal is to transfer data from Journey Builder back to Sales Cloud.

Comment: I'm not sure what Preference Centres have to do with what you're trying to achieve. What data do you want to have available in CRM?

Answer (score 0):

In order to transfer data from Journey Builder to Sales Cloud, you have a couple of options available to you.

- Email Tracking Results will be displayed in the email sent list
- If each journey represents a particular campaign or flow, I would suggest that you create campaigns for this in SF Core and use create campaign member activity to relate the contact to that
- If you need other data that you generate mid-journey, you can use the SF Object Activity to update specific fields
- If you need data from SMS or Push, pushed back into SF, it is a bit more complex and will require scripting, unless you can achieve desired functionality with decision splits and update data / SF object activities
- If you want aggregated numbers - e.g. Email Clicks etc. you need to first create the numbers using SQL and then design a process that can move the data from MC to SF (might require an ETL to not put unnecessary strain on the SF APIs)

Hope this clarifies - if not, pleasy specify what data you are looking for?